# Code runs fine on editor but has an EOF error in Code Wars

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and just joined Code Wars a day ago. So I had a Kata called "Alan Partridge II - Apple Turnover".

It basically told me to do this:
"Your job is simple, if (x) squared is more than 1000, return 'It's hotter than the sun!!', else, return
'Help yourself to a honeycomb Yorkie for the glovebox.'.
X will be a valid integer number.
X will be either a number or a string. Both are valid."

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
import math
def apple(x):
    if math.sqrt(x)>=1000:
        print("It's hotter than the sun!!")
    else:
        print("Help yourself to a honeycomb Yorkie for the glovebox.")
apple(x=int(input("gimme a temp\n")))
```

When I tried it on Pycharm, I'm pretty sure everything works. But when I tested it on Code Wars, this happened:

```
Log
gimme a temp
STDERR
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 2, in <module>
    from solution import apple
  File "/workspace/default/solution.py", line 7, in <module>
    apple(x=int(input('gimme a temp')))
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Here is the screenshot of my test results:
[image: Here is the screenshot of my test results]

Since I'm new, I'm not really sure what's going on.

Can anyone please help me to figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Maybe adding a new empty line after the 7th line would fix it?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Code Wars imports the function to its own code and then runs it. The problem is that when importing a function, Python will run your whole file. It does probably not expect you to run the `input()` function. You can solve this by putting your own function call in an `if __name__== "__main__":` statement like this:

```
import math
def apple(x):
    if math.sqrt(x)>=1000:
        print("It's hotter than the sun!!")
    else:
        print("Help yourself to a honeycomb Yorkie for the glovebox.")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    apple(x=int(input("gimme a temp\n")))
```

The if-statement basically checks if you are running the file itself, or importing it from another Python script. So when Code Wars tries to validate your function, it will import it and not execute your own function call.